# Emacs: Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig

Tags: emacs, gnupg

Recently tried to update emacs packages and got this.

```
Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
No public key for 066DAFCB81E42C40 created at 2019-10-02T10:10:02+0100 using RSA
Command output:
gpg: Signature made Wed 02 Oct 2019 10:10:02 AM BST
gpg:                using RSA key C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/ for the same question.

The signature check failed because you don't have the new key (the old signature key expired on Sep 23).  The new key is available from the usual GPG key-servers, comes with Emacs≥26.3, and can also be obtained by installing the package [gnu-elpa-keyring-update](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html).

Comment: I see that the options are either disable signature verification (that I obviously do not want to do) or download package that do it for me. Is it possible just import the new keys to gpg without installing side dependencies?

Comment: well i see this error when i tried to install "Failed to verify signature: "gnu-elpa-keyring-update-2019.3.tar.sig"

Comment: @papachan Did you also try the option to update manually with gpg? Currently `gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40` (see the package’s website)

Comment: @papachan, see the README of gnu-elpa-keyring-update which offers workarounds.

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster the command gives me `gpg: Invalid option "--receive-keys"`

Comment: @Asalle Funny. I'm not a gpg expert, but 2.2.19 lists this  option in the help output (`gpg --help`). Are you using an older version?

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster yes, it turned out I used an outdated version

Comment: got `gpg: keyserver receive failed: General error` on gpg --receive-keys. No way to install `gnu-elpa-keyring-update` neither.

Comment: I have followed the same steps and I also get the "General error" message as @jaromrax

Comment: Got the same 'General error', so tried the 'modify expiration date', but got: gpg: "474F05837FBDEF9B" is not a fingerprint. For now I guess its 'temporarily disable signature verification'.

Comment: I get that failure with 27.2…

Answer (score 3):

Try renaming your `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg` file to something else as a backup and then run `M-x package-refresh-contents`. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error in Windows 10 including the following line

```
gpg: keyblock resource '/c/Users/<theuser>/c:/Users/<theuser>/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/pubring.kbx': No such file or directory
```

It turned out that Emacs was using the GnuPG installed via MSYS2. Installing the Windows version of GnuPG (Gpg4win) solved it.